# What's the meaning behind chapter colors in The Ickabog?

Tags: the-ickabog

The website for ["The Ickabog"](https://theickabog.com/read-the-story/) by JK Rowling has color coding for various chapters.

[image: Screenshot of The Ickabog home page, as on 07 June 2020 showing boxes for each chapter with border colour on each of them]

The color schemes repeat as well:

[image: chapters 18 and 19 of The Ickabog showing the boxes with yellow border colours repeating from eariler]

Do we know what's the color scheme here?

Comment: Were they released in batches?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a certain colour of chapter means it was released on the same day. For example, the first two chapters, which are both coloured purple, would have been released the same day.

Comment: So looks like repeated colors are just incidental, not intentional. I'll mark this as accepted once we have a few more releases to confirm this completely (there are 34 chapters planned)

Comment: Can you provide some evidence to back this up?